# boost date immutable - so how can use it in a loop?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

boost pdate is immutable, so how can I use it in a loop? I need to make comparison with last-dealt-with date:

```
    date last(neg_infin);
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (tasks[i]->getTime().date() > last) {
                cout << ":::" << tasks[i]->getTime().date() << ":::" << endl;
            }
            cout << "[" << i << "]" << '\t';
            tasks[i]->print();
            // i need to change the last date here
            cout << endl;
        }
```

ie. if the date part of current time is later than the previous, print the date, otherwise print only the time

Comment: Do you need to change or just display? you are mixing both..

Comment: I need to display tasks[i]->getTime().date() only if it's different than the last one displayed, so I thought I could remember the last one in "last" object of type "date", but I can't change it. It doesn't have the '=' operator.

Comment: Ah so you need to modify the `last` element? Instead of `last`, why dont you just compare with i-1 th element? or keep a pointer `date *last`

Comment: As per boost documentation "the date class is immutable
once constructed although it does allow assignment from another date".So you can very well do last = tasks[i]->getTime().date()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need an explicit last element? Wont this work as well?

```
if (i == 0 || tasks[i]->getTime().date() > tasks[i-1]->getTime.date()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're dealing with indexes into `tasks` already, instead store the "last" index, rather than the date.

```
int lastIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        if (tasks[i]->getTime().date() > tasks[lastIndex]->getTime.date()) {
            cout << ":::" << tasks[i]->getTime().date() << ":::" << endl;

        }
        cout << "[" << i << "]" << '\t';
        tasks[i]->print();

        lastIndex = i;

        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If you want it to print for i == 0, you should add that condition